# If $G=\langle x\rangle$ is cyclic group and order of $G$ is $40$ then how many order of $x^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

If $G=\langle x\rangle$ is cyclic group and order of $G$ is $40$ then how many order of $x^3$

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). Also, because you’ve written so little, it’s very difficult to tell what you’re actually asking. At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: Yup, the question is in need of improvement. A) it is lacking in context, which we require at least from questions that look like homework assignments. B) what is $x$? Oh, Martin Sleziak fixed that (Do. Not. Rely on the question title ALONE for key pieces of information). C) The formula for the order of a power of an element of a known order has appeared so many times on our site that I have lost count. You should search first.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ is relatively prime to $40$, so there is an integer $k$ (in this case $k = 27$) such that $3k \equiv 1 \pmod {40}$. Thus $\langle x\rangle \supset \langle x^3\rangle \supset \langle(x^{27})^{3}\rangle = \langle x\rangle$, so $x^3$ is also order $40$.

Comment: then order of x^15 is the same ans ?

Comment: @AongWa is 15 relatively prime to 40?

Comment: no thanks for ans ^-^

Comment: @Aong Wa Why do you use rude comments like this one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Imagine a comma (or a full stop even) between "no" and "thanks for ans". Apparently the asker is not very experienced in expressing themself in English.

Comment: I see ! A funny example of misunderstanding due to lack of punctuation...